# How to send real time data variable between function and variable?

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I'd like to assign to double variable (param1) result of one function.

```
{
//we are inside one function
double param1 = function();
}
```

captured_values() must capture in real time double variable. This variable I would like to assign by function() to my param1

```
program1::program1(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
captured_values(){ //here function() should be used - to send captured value to param1}
}
```

Should I use signal and slots mechanism or maybe other one? Could someone please give complete code example?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, for applications receiving real-time data, they have two threads.  One thread fetches the data and stores into one or more buffers. The other thread reads the data and processes it. Is your scenario like this?

Comment: Hi, You're right. In my case it's two functions which handle it

Comment: Answer could be structure in which parameters are stored by emit function and then in other part of program, variable can be updated by function which read value from stucture